# How to prevent validation errors of empty optional fields?

Tags: angular

```
<input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" email autocomplete="off"/>
```

when I try to submit the form, this field raises a validation error when empty `{email: true}`

is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you please post your Component code as well?

Comment: i think you can do that on reactive form, make custom validation. so if empty  return null, if not empty do some validation for email